# Downgrading iOS on iPhone SE 1st Gen

Tags: iphone, ios, downgrade

I have many clients in developing countries, where they are using old iPhone SE (1st generation) devices, without sufficient internet access to install updates.

As a developer providing aid to these countries, I find myself having to ensure my software, websites, apps etc... remain compatible.

My iPhone SE (also 1st Generation) is using iOS 15.8 the most recent update.

How can I downgrade my personal device?